# Someone erased the mac os x with ubuntu, how do i get it back?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, mac

so for a further detail about this, my friend has a macbook pro thats all i know about it specfically aside from the fact it was running os x lion. before this guy got a hold of the computer that he knows, I could hit the command key and the R key to get to the disk utilities and what-not to install OS X Lion on it, but now since whomever my friend let touch th mac, i no longer and do any of the start-up keys for it.. I've been trying to geth the mac os x lion on there and im having no luck what-so-ever, if anyone could help me with this i would be greatly appreciative... if you need anymore info that i may be able to provide please feel free to ask. thank you again.

Comment: Is your question "How to install MacOS after being erased by Ubuntu?"? If so this does not belong here and would better be fit for http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: if the Mac OSX was erased, you have to reinstall it.
The long answer: an expert can bring you back some of your files which wasn't overwritten physically, but don't try to fix it by yourself!

### Instructions to recover:

- Make a copy of your HDD to an image file with `dd` (`sudo dd if=/your/hdd of=backup.img`)
- Use `photorec` to search for your lost files. (full instructions of usage [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec))

Note, that you will need a huge storage big enough to keep the backup.img file and the recovered files as well.

Comment: no i want to fix it myself please instruct me on the ways cuz i want to know

Comment: There are the instructions. Remember, that this will hopefully recover just your personal files like pictures and documents, not the whole system!

Comment: i dont want to recover the pictures... i want to re-put the OS on it

Comment: Then take an OSX installer DVD and go ahead!

Comment: Press C while booting. It will boot from the disk!